# OpenMage LTS 20.01 - Freeshipping not applying

Tags: magento-1.9, free-shipping, openmage

I have 2 installs of OpenMage 20.01.  Neither will apply the Freeshipping method.

I believe the issue is with  app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Freeshipping.php

```
if (($request->getFreeShipping())
    || ($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() >= $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal'))
```

$request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() is always returning zero.

I applied the work around at this link to "fix" the issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489068/magento-free-shipping-not-working

Can anyone confirm if this is a bug within OpenMage and if there is a better fix?

Answer (score 0):

I can (at least) confirm that this has not been introduced with OpenMage ... ;)

Please raise an issue [here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/issues/new/choose) and add some steps to reproduce this easily. I (just) guess there is better fix.

<sub>(I hope its okay to just link to OM to have it on screen there)</sub>